# Get the virtual path of an action from outside the controller

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.2.7 targeting .NET framework 4.6.1.

From inside, say a business object, and specifically not from within a Controller or a View, how do I get the virtual path, i.e. the full url of an action.

Such that:

```
"~/Action/Controller/param"
```

becomes

```
"/Action/Controller/param"
```

> **Why?**
>
> For those wondering what the big deal is, and that why don't I just
>   remove the leading tilde (~) character, the two paths (the one with
>   and the one without the tilde) can be different in the event that your
>   web application is not deployed in the site root directory.
>
> For e.g. you have a website mapped to `domain.com/foo`. Then, you
>   would like `"~/Controller/Action"` to return `/foo/Controller/Action`.

For e.g.

```
class MyBusinessObject
{
  public void DoSomething()
  {
    // From here, what do I do such that
    // "~/Controller/Action/param" becomes
    // /Controller/Action/param
    // without doing it by hand
  }
}

class MyController : Mvc.Controller
{
  public ActionResult SomeAction()
  {
    new MyBusinessObject().DoSomething();

    ...

    return View();
  }
}
```

Is there already a method in MVC or in the .NET framework libraries?

In other words, if I could call the `Url.Content()` extension from outside the Controller, that would do it.

I've done this many times before but I'll always forget and post a question about it. But I can't find my previous question about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I suddenly remembered as soon as I wrote "if I could call the `Url.Helper`" in the question.

Even though the `Content` method of the `UrlHelper` class is public, you cannot use it from outside a Controller like so:

```
class BusinessObject
{
  void DoSomething()
  {
    var url = System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.Content("~/Controller/Action/param");
  }
}
```

because internally it calls another method passing it the `HttpContext` obejct like so:

```
public virtual string Content(string contentPath)
{
    return GenerateContentUrl(contentPath, RequestContext.HttpContext);
}
```

However, that `GenerateContentUrl` method, which it calls, is also `public`. And it is also `static`, so no need to create a `UrlHelper` object. So, we can call that like so:

```
var virtualPath = System.Web.Mvc.UrlHelper.GenerateContentUrl(
                   "~/Action/Controller/Param", 
                   new HttpContextWrapper(HttpContext.Current));
```